# Add description and title field to each image

Tags: entities, media

I am creating an image Album. For this I have created one content type with "Album Title"(title), "Album Description"(body) and Image field which can take unlimited number of images. Now I want to add a title and description to each image.
Please help me to short it out.

Comment: are you using drupal 6 or 7 ?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Media module, you can add fields to images, such as description or caption.
https://drupal.org/project/media

Alternatively, you could use the Field collection module to create a 'Gallery image' field type, which has the extra fields that you need.

Comment: Thanks!! Fields Collection module helped me in this context. But the Field collection module is causing problem while working with views.

Comment: Have you enabled the field collection views module?

Answer (score 4):

You can add the title field and alt field, but not sure about the description field.

Go to `admin/structure/types` and then click **manage fields** for the particular content type and then click **edit** under operations for image field you want and then check the title field as shown in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the alt field only appears when the image can not be loaded and the title field is shown as tool tip. I need a description field so that it can appear along with the image.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Bala said, you can use the [image field caption](https://drupal.org/project/image_field_caption) module

> Adds an extra text area for captions on image fields.
>
> Similar to the alt and title text fields available with an image
>   field, the caption text area can be used to enter text or html
>   descriptions of an image.

In case you need to style the caption, copy the image_field_caption.tpl.php file and place it in your theme's directory

Comment: I dont see the caption field with the latest drupal 7 and image field caption module...

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find the solution for the problem you are facing by now, this is how I did it. Within your Content type element that you created, say GALLERY, in the manage fields section add another field and call it "image_title". Within the manage display section of the same, make it visible and in line with the image you are using as your gallery element. Save your work.

Once you create a new Gallery content you will need to add the title of each image youa re adding to it. After that titles of the images should be visible in your colorbox galery. That was the thing that you were missing?

I hope this helps.

Best regards

KuzmaN